# How to know if a linear transformation is onto

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

[image: near]

---

The question shows a linear transformation and asks to show that it is isomorphic. I understand the one-to-one part, but don't understand the onto part. The solution manual explains it this way :

---

[image]

---

What does "the image of this member of the domain..." mean? I can't understand it and don't get how it proves the function is onto.

I apologize if the question is too simple or if I'm asking a dumb question.

Comment: alternatively, you may prove it surjective by proving it injective instead, since both the vector space have the same dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that$$f\bigl((s+t)+tx\bigr)=\begin{pmatrix}s\\t\end{pmatrix}.$$This proves that every element of $\mathbb R^2$ can be written as $f\bigl(P(x)\bigr)$, for some $P(x)\in\mathcal P_1$; in other words, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification! Is there an easier way to prove that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: I don't think so. This is how I would do it.